# Accessing nested values in REST API from php code

Tags: php, rest

I need to access all the values from API response and display them in an html table with these columns: "date", "dimes5", "score", "teams", "rot", "opening".

This is what I tried:

```
<?php

$games = 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/3d3b5493-d501-4511-ad8f-43c168833999/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Famericasline.com%2FStats%2FOdds%2FBasketball%2FNBA&&_apikey=db29c3b561c1433bba0d365d7a9c88273c2fcf188f2cd1d215b7dcec1d9ac1880677b574fee6662ac330c8d5ee5358bcc590b5cfce5be1db4ed163b18ba25bc8389603dff096f62a637c9b4bc296c70d';

$games_json = file_get_contents($games);
$games_array = (array)json_decode($games_json, true);

//echo $games_array['results'][date];
print_r($games_array);

$dt = $games_array['results'];
```

This is REST API response:

```
{
  "outputProperties": [
    {
      "type": "STRING",
      "name": "date"
    },
    {
      "type": "STRING",
      "name": "rot"
    },
    {
      "type": "STRING",
      "name": "teams"
    },
    {
      "type": "STRING",
      "name": "opening"
    },
    {
      "type": "STRING",
      "name": "dimes5"
    },
    {
      "type": "STRING",
      "name": "score"
    }
  ],
  "pageUrl": "http://americasline.com/Stats/Odds/Basketball/NBA",
  "connectorGuid": "3d3b5493-d501-4511-ad8f-43c168833999",
  "connectorVersionGuid": "4727fd71-3b59-4254-8e5e-299da2e43a2f",
  "cookies": [
    "SESS0d8800e218fbe5dbb1d5b44365860b7a=\"2cca2078486d68291cebf2a7845cdcaa\";Path=\"/\";Domain=\"americasline.com\";Port=\"80\""
  ],
  "results": [
    {
      "opening": "-6½-105",
      "rot": "505",
      "teams": "San Antonio",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "-7-101",
      "date": "03/07/2016"
    },
    {
      "opening": "198o-110",
      "rot": "506",
      "teams": "Indiana",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "195½o-102",
      "date": "7:00 PM"
    },
    {
      "opening": "203½o-110",
      "rot": "503",
      "teams": "Memphis",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "203½o-105",
      "date": "03/07/2016"
    },
    {
      "opening": "-10-110",
      "rot": "504",
      "teams": "Cleveland",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "-12½-105",
      "date": "7:00 PM"
    },
    {
      "opening": "212o-110",
      "rot": "501",
      "teams": "Minnesota",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "215o-102",
      "date": "03/07/2016"
    },
    {
      "opening": "-8½-110",
      "rot": "502",
      "teams": "Charlotte",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "-10-102",
      "date": "7:00 PM"
    },
    {
      "opening": "209o-110",
      "rot": "509",
      "teams": "Milwaukee",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "210o-103",
      "date": "03/07/2016"
    },
    {
      "opening": "-6-110",
      "rot": "510",
      "teams": "Chicago",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "-7-102",
      "date": "8:00 PM"
    },
    {
      "opening": "219½o-110",
      "rot": "507",
      "teams": "Sacramento",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "-1-105",
      "date": "03/07/2016"
    },
    {
      "opening": "-2-110",
      "rot": "508",
      "teams": "New Orleans",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "219o-107",
      "date": "8:00 PM"
    },
    {
      "opening": "-2-110",
      "rot": "511",
      "teams": "LA Clippers",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "-5-108",
      "date": "03/07/2016"
    },
    {
      "opening": "211½o-110",
      "rot": "512",
      "teams": "Dallas",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "209o-105",
      "date": "8:30 PM"
    },
    {
      "opening": "222½o-110",
      "rot": "513",
      "teams": "Orlando",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "224o-108",
      "date": "03/07/2016"
    },
    {
      "opening": "-15-110",
      "rot": "514",
      "teams": "Golden State",
      "score": "0",
      "dimes5": "-14½-103",
      "date": "10:30 PM"
    },
    {
      "rot": "701",
      "teams": "Brooklyn",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "03/08/2016"
    },
    {
      "rot": "702",
      "teams": "Toronto",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "7:30 PM"
    },
    {
      "rot": "703",
      "teams": "San Antonio",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "03/08/2016"
    },
    {
      "rot": "704",
      "teams": "Minnesota",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "8:00 PM"
    },
    {
      "rot": "707",
      "teams": "New York",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "03/08/2016"
    },
    {
      "rot": "708",
      "teams": "Denver",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "9:00 PM"
    },
    {
      "rot": "705",
      "teams": "Atlanta",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "03/08/2016"
    },
    {
      "rot": "706",
      "teams": "Utah",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "9:00 PM"
    },
    {
      "rot": "709",
      "teams": "Washington",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "03/08/2016"
    },
    {
      "rot": "710",
      "teams": "Portland",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "10:00 PM"
    },
    {
      "rot": "711",
      "teams": "Orlando",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "03/08/2016"
    },
    {
      "rot": "712",
      "teams": "LA Lakers",
      "score": "0",
      "date": "10:30 PM"
    }
  ],
  "offset": 0
}
```

Comment: So you have an array in `$games_array` so process over that array picking out what you want to show on the page

Comment: Please don't use picture for textual content. Also, always keep the content in the question and not on external sites, as question should be able to stand on its own. It's also helpful to start with a description of your problem, rather than dumping necessary in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked fairly obvious and straight forward to start with, but I also notice that in the result array not all the fields appear on all the occurances so I have added a little check on each field in the sub array so that you dont get errors and added a default value `&nbsp;` so something is  placed in all the table cells where no data is available.

```
<?php
$games = 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/3d3b5493-d501-4511-ad8f-43c168833999/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Famericasline.com%2FStats%2FOdds%2FBasketball%2FNBA&&_apikey=db29c3b561c1433bba0d365d7a9c88273c2fcf188f2cd1d215b7dcec1d9ac1880677b574fee6662ac330c8d5ee5358bcc590b5cfce5be1db4ed163b18ba25bc8389603dff096f62a637c9b4bc296c70d';

$games_json = file_get_contents($games);
$games_array = (array)json_decode($games_json, true);

//echo $games_array['results'][date];
//print_r($games_array);

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>Date</td><td>dimes5</td><td>score</td><td>rot</td><td>opening</td></tr>';
foreach ( $games_array['results'] as $result) {

    $date    = isset($result['date']) ? $result['date'] : '&nbsp;';
    $dimes5  = isset($result['dimes5']) ? $result['dimes5'] : '&nbsp;';
    $score   = isset($result['score']) ? $result['score'] : '&nbsp;';
    $rot     = isset($result['rot']) ? $result['rot'] : '&nbsp;';
    $opening = isset($result['opening']) ? $result['opening'] : '&nbsp;';

    echo sprintf('<tr><td>%s<td><td>%s<td><td>%s<td><td>%s<td><td>%s<td></tr>',
                      $date,
                      $dimes5,
                      $score,
                      $rot,
                      $opening);
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

result is an array so try this

```
$games_json = file_get_contents($games);
$games_array = json_decode($games_json);

foreach ($games_array->results as $result)
{
 echo $result->date;
 echo $result->dimes5;

// do the stuffs here with values
}
```